# Failing to call a containerized web service using REST API from outside the container

Tags: docker, rest, amazon-ec2

We have a Spring Boot Hello World application that ingests a /hello REST API and returns a string. The application works when run on a PC.

We deployed the application in a container on AWS EC2 RHEL 7 instance. The container is using a base RHEL 7 image as well. The application starts with no issues in a container, but when we are trying to send the API call, we are getting

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to <EC2 IP address> port 80 after 21003 ms: Couldn't connect to server.
```

When running docker with --network flag as follows:

```
docker run -- network host -d hello_world:tag
```

our REST API call from the same EC2 instance as the container returns a response as expected.

When running docker without the --network flag, as follows:

```
docker run --name hello--rm -p 8080:8080 -d hello-world:tag
```

We are getting the error above.

So the issue is clearly not with the application, but with some networking configuration for the image itself or the EC2 instance.

EC2 instance inbound rules are configured to accept traffic from all IPv4 sources on ports 22 (SSH), 80 (HTTP), 443 (HTTPS). We can ping the EC2 instance from any machine as well.